# Save user preferences in popup.html Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've finished developing the main functionality of a Chrome Extension, but I'm struggling to retain the user preferences in the popup.html file. So, I have a button in the popup.html file which is supposed to be a user preference, but I am not able to retain the user preference upon reloading the page and clicking on the extension again.

I tried using the Chrome Storage API, but I was unable to achieve what I wanted.
Here is a picture of popup.html:

[image]

I want to be able to save a user's preference if they choose to toggle between on and off. But as of what I have now, when the user slides it on (as indicated in the picture), upon clicking away from the popup and clicking the icon again, the button always defaults to the 'off' position.

I tried using a combination of localStorage and the Chrome Storage API to load the user preferences, but I was unable to do so.

Here is my popup.js file:

```
function saveChanges() {
    // Get a value.
    if ($('#myonoffswitch').is(':checked')) {
        localStorage.mydata = 'y';
    } else {
        localStorage.mydata = 'n';
    }
    // Save it using the Chrome extension storage API.
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'value': localStorage.mydata
    }, function () {

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('mydata')) {
        if (localStorage.mydata == 'n') {
            $('myonoffswitch').attr('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('myonoffswitch').attr('checked', true);
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#myonoffswitch').is(':checked')) {
            localStorage.setItem('mydata', 'y');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('mydata', 'n');
        }
    }

    $('#myonoffswitch').click(function () {
        saveChanges();
    });

});
```

Here is my popup.html file:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Replace some text</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.12.3.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <div class='logo'>

        </div>
        <div class='main-text'>

        </div>
        <div class='buttons-area'>
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
            </div>
            <div class='block-spoilers-message'>
                On Off Button
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And finally, here is a relevant part of my content script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var on_off_pref = true;

    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function (changes, namespace) {
        for (key in changes) {
            var storageChange = changes[key];
            on_off_pref = storageChange.newValue;
            console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
                'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
                key,
                namespace,
                storageChange.oldValue,
                storageChange.newValue);
        }
    });

    if (on_off_pref === 'y') {
        //Execute main functionality here only if the button in popup.html is on.
    }
});
```

So, in short, I need to preserve the settings on popup.html and use those settings in the content script to determine whether or not to run the main part.
I have looked at the other StackOverflow solutions, but I have not been able to get any of them to work.
Any help on resolving this issue would be thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: Voting to close as typo. You just forgot `#` in `$('myonoffswitch').attr('checked', true);`

Comment: I recently wrote a module to manage the options: [webext-options-sync](https://github.com/fregante/webext-options-sync). The form will also automatically sync with the saved options

Answer (score 0):

1. see what [@Xan said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221681/save-user-preferences-in-popup-html-chrome-extension?rq=1#comment61979529_37221681)

> You just forgot `#` in `$('myonoffswitch').attr('checked', true);`

2. your webextension needs the `storage` permission. See https://sites.google.com/site/getsnippet/browser/chrome/extensions/storage